# openCV imdecode works slowly

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working with MJPEG big sequences (e.g. 3000 JPEGs in sequence). I'm holding this JPEG sequence in vector of object containing JPEG data as `std::vector<char> vBufferPFDecode`. I want to show this data with openCV `hightGUI` methods (imshow), so I have to convert it to `cv::Mat` type with method:

```
cv::Mat pMat=cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(vBufferPFDecode), -1 );
```

It works, but to slowly - I can only get 8-10 frames per second. Do you know any alternative methods?

Comment: did you ever find a workaround to get a faster fps on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are allocating a whole new frame each time, instead of using the data and attaching it to a MatHeader.

Please Post the entire code to confirm.